# SQL Relationships: 2 FK to one PK

Tags: sql

i have one user_table with PK_usernames
i have another item_table with FK_owner and FK_checkoutUser

how can i set the relationships in a way, that i can have a on Update do cascade.
So that when the PK_username is changed, items that have the user as owner or checkoutUser will be changed as well?

I get a warning of circular dependencies if i just set both the FK to OnUpdate: cascade

Comment: Not an answer, but I can't help but feel that issuing an id to each user that is static and acts as your primary and foreign key would be a much better approach, holistically, than relying on cascade if username changes are common on your application. Is that a possibility?

Comment: its something i have been thinking about, but never taken the initiative to start... maybe its finally time...

Comment: For sure. I'm surprised someone hasn't popped into this question to give you a direct answer about your cascade yet. It looks like you are lacking a tag for the RDBMS you are using. Which platform are you using (mysql, postgres, oracle, snowflake, sql-server, etc)?